# Most inseparable combinations?

Tags: disassembly

Some combinations of pieces are really hard to get apart – really hard. Can some answerers provide a list of “dangerous combos“? For example, a 2×2 with a round 2×2 on bottom. Also, if possible, provide a good way to get them apart!

Comment: There are some combinations that are almost impossible to separate, such as this "brick paradox": http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/982/can-an-axle-be-removed-from-this-brick-paradox

Comment: I use an axle to separate stuck parts. It has always works for me.

Comment: There is an interesting thread on Eurobricks about "deadly" assemblies: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/81402-impossible-lego/#comment-1564353

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 1x1 round plate on the bottom of a 1x1 square plate is pretty difficult to get apart. The Santa's Workshop set uses transparent 1x1 round plates stuck until 1x1 plates with a clip on top to make Christmas lights. I just left the whole thing assembled; I'll probably never bother taking that apart.

Also: if you stick some brand-new 4x4 plates together it can be very very hard to separate them. Lots of clutch, lots of rigidity, so even with 5 brick separators it is difficult work.

Answer (score 19):

My son did some extensive research on this subject, which yielded this beauty:

[image: Light bulb stuck in Duplo stud]

That’s a [light bulb cover](//www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4773) stuck into a Duplo stud. While it may look harmless, I found it impossible to get sufficient hold of the lightbulb before levering it out with a very thin screwdriver.

Comment: Would it help to use a plastic straw and some suction?

Comment: @zovits: I honestly don’t want to test this, but I strongly doubt that you can build up enough force for this. Also, you would have to find a straw that exactly fits around the light bulb.

Answer (score 6):

I have a 3062b (round 1x1 open stud) stuck in the middle of a 6067 (boat mast section base 4x4) and I can't get it off. The round 1x1 fits over the post thingy in the center of the mast base and the side walls of the mast base prevent access to the grove at the bottom of the 1x1 round. The inner diameter of the mast base is small enough and tight enough that any antenna type pieces inserted through the bottom can't catch the lip at the top of the 1x1 round on the way through.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'd say a 4265a on a 3649 are among the hardest to separate. But a 3647 is more painful due to the teeth

http://rebrickable.com/parts/3749
[image]

http://rebrickable.com/parts/4265a
[image]

http://rebrickable.com/parts/3647
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A 1x1 tile stuck inside the bottom of a 2x4 brick is very difficult to get out. No Brick Separator will help you there.

Answer (score 3):

The [Brick Separator](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Brick-Separator-630) can be employed successfully in a majority of cases where bricks are stuck together.

The hardest thing to remove I believe is [Technic pins 4459](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4459#T=C) wherever used. See [separate question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4245/how-to-unplug-black-friction-pin-connectors).

Comment: When I was a kid I had 6 Technic sets that I loved and played a lot with. Those pesky pins without center slots would pull up a very strong fight.. but were always not enough for my child persistence :) I never had one pin broke down on me, I just loved too much those beautiful (for the time) Technic sets !

Answer (score 2):

Generally, early BIONICLE body bricks can encounter issues with this, due to their bulky, specially-designed nature. For instance, the [Toa Mata body gearbox](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=32489#T=C) has a particular danger area inside it. If one places the [#2 axle connector hub](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=32034#T=C) horizontally inside the neck area and sticks a [2-long axle](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=32062#T=C) in either side, the result is completely irreversible.

This is akin to some of the 'brick paradoxes' mentioned in [this blog post](http://www.technicbricks.com/2008/10/dont-do-this-at-home.html), which I found linked in a question while browsing the tag selection a few days ago. There are plenty more to be found in Technic construction; after all, Bryson's Second Law of Repairs, a corollary of Murphy's Law, states: "If you fool around with a thing for very long you will screw it up."

Comment: Wow, the Toa Mata gearbox is especially hazardous since many of the sets contain all the pieces to get it stuck!

Answer (score 2):

Also, part 99009 and Part 99010 is another one that is extremely hard to disassemble as highlight in [this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/how-to-disassemble-this-technic-combination-part-99009-from-part-99010). (The current brick separator will not work in this situation.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like a huge problem, since these are designed that way. The combination is effectively one part.

Answer (score 1):

Another inseparable part is the[image: H-piece]
if you put enough of them together side by side many times

Answer (score 1):

A 1x1 tile stuck to a 1x1 round plate was the hardest, I think harder than the accepted answer above, until I used two LEGO brick spectators in opposite directions. Put the stuck pieces on top of one separator facing north, pry with a second one facing south. Pops them apart beautifully.

Small plates stuck together can be separate using two LEGO separators, but both in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

A 1x1 round tile on 1x1 round plate.

You can't use a brick separator, because tiles don't have studs.

Comment: You're using the wrong end of the brick separator. The fat end has a strong, thin edge which can fit between the two - then twist. I just did this now to test it. I presume it's why the 1x1 round tile has a lip.

Comment: It should be possible to use one of the studs on top of the brick separator with the antistud of the plate to grab it and provide enough leverage via holding the plate to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 1x1 round plate with one end of a "string with end studs" stuck on top of it surprisingly difficult to get apart with my bare hands, without ripping the string off. [image: string with end-studs]

If you have 2 brick separators available (one above and one below), or a plate and a brick separator it is easy as you can lock each piece, but with bare hands it is completely impossible.