# What are some "Illegal" LEGO combinations?

Tags: challenge

On [Brothers Brick](http://www.brothers-brick.com/lego-glossary/), there is an AFOL term for bad LEGO combos: **Illegal**.  These combinations are "unconventional" and put stress on the bricks. Essentially, they are nonconformist, risky maneuvers, typically compromising the integrity of any parts in it.

For example -- from the site -- wedging a flat plate between studs on a brick.  I have used this term before, and can testify to dangerous combinations. So I'm posing this as another challenge for the community, like my [hard to separate combos](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7588/most-inseparable-combinations).

**What are some Illegal combinations * you* have found?** Largest number of unique combos wins! (please don't *try* to kill anything for this.)

Comment: I would again politely ask the community to like the question being answered as general policy, after all, no good questions means no good answers!

Comment: How can LEGO building techniques be illegal? Would you be put In jail for using on? I like to wonder

Comment: "Illegal" is just the word lego designers use to define building techniques that are considered undesirable because:
- they place stress on te elements, making them wear out
- they cause elements to be out of sync, making them difficult to combine with standard building techniques or difficult to model with designer software
- they make the set difficult to assemble or dissassemble for a kid
- ...

There are of course no repercussions if you use these techniques anyway, it is your LEGO...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not think it is up to us to determine what is considered an Illegal Technique - TLG (The LEGO Group) determines this for their commercial products. It depends on how much of a purist you are whether you apply these constraints in your own builds. 
That said, [LEGO Designer Jamie Berard has made a presentation](http://bramlambrecht.com/tmp/jamieberard-brickstress-bf06.pdf) in the past that highlights most Illegal Techniques.

Some examples:

- Studs-on-side bricks cannot have their side stud in the hole of a
  technic brick
- Bricks mounted SNOT style onto Ehrling/Headlight bricks cannot sit
  directly above a normal stud (the minimal height of the LEGO
  embossing makes that combination illegal)
- Technic pins have to be fully inserted into technic holes, otherwise they stay in compressed state which causes stress on the element.
- Plates cannot be inserted with their studs into technic bricks, unless it is a 1x1 plate (so only 1 hole is used) and there is no brick attached to the technic brick directly above the inserted plate.
- As mentioned by you already, you cannot insert plates between studs (this used to be a valid technique 20+ years ago, but is no longer considered "legal" by LEGO).

Comment: LEGO designers are also strongly discouraged from ever directly mating polycarbonate or transparent pieces. I don't know if this counts as "illegal" or if there is any official set that breaks this rule.

Comment: @jdv certain trans pieces cannot be used with other trans pieces because the plastic forms a chemical bond between the elements. The linked PDF gives the example of a transparent bar inserted into another transparent element such as a cone. Stud-to-stud connections are still allowed.

Comment: Is putting a round piece between four studs legal?

Answer (score 11):

One illegal technique I've seen was two elements stuck together using a sticker to bind them. The builder claimed that the solution was "purist" because it was a lego sticker from a set.

Comment: This is not even a building technique. :)

Comment: @Aziraphale It was used in a moc to hold pieces together... depends on your point of view I guess. Load-bearing stickers.