# How to disassemble this small Technic turntable, combination of parts 99009 and 99010?

Tags: technic, disassembly

How should I non-destructively disassemble the following parts, when they are newly assembled?

**99009 Light Bluish Gray Technic Turntable Small Bottom**

[image: 99009 Light Bluish Gray Technic Turntable Small Bottom]

**99010 Black Technic Turntable Small Top**

[image: 99010 Black Technic Turntable Small Top]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These parts do not come apart. They are designed to be clicked into place and then remain connected. I have not found nor heard of a way that these can be separated without damaging the plastic and hence the functioning of the part.

The assembled component has part number [99009c01 - Technic Turntable Small, Complete Assembly with Black Outside Gear Section](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99009c01#T=C).

[image]

Comment: So, Part 99009 together with part 99010 will be one of those brick paradox (can be assemble once and cannot be disassemble)?

Comment: Not sure if it's a "paradox", but yes, once assembled the end result is a new part that cannot be returned to its original components. The new part's name is [99009c01](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99009c01#T=C). I've added this info to my answer.